# Why doesn't this code correctly read strings until encountering a newline?

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I'm trying to write a program that reads a bunch of strings from the user, then a newline, and pushes all the strings I've read onto a stack. Here's what I have so far:

```
stack<string> st;
string str;
while(str != "\n")
{
    cin >> str;
    st.push(str);
}
```

However, this goes into an infinite loop and doesn't stop when I read a newline. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the stream extraction operator (the `>>` operator) as applied to strings will skip over all whitespace. If you type in `A B C`, then a newline, then `D E F`, then try reading strings one at a time using the stream extraction operator, you'll get the strings "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", and "F" with no whitespace and no newlines.

If you want to read a bunch of strings until you hit a newline, you can consider using `std::getline` to read a line of text, then use an `std::istringstream` to tokenize it:

```
#include <sstream>

/* Read a full line from the user. */
std::string line;
if (!getline(std::cin, line)) {
    // Handle an error
}

/* Tokenize it. */
std::istringstream tokenizer(line);
for (std::string token; tokenizer >> token; ) {
   // Do something with the string token
}
```

As a note - in your original code, you have a loop that generally looks like this:

```
string toRead;
while (allIsGoodFor(toRead)) {
    cin >> toRead;
    // do something with toRead;
}
```

This approach, in general, doesn't work because it will continue through the loop one time too many. Specifically, once you read an input that causes the condition to be false, the loop will keep processing what you've read so far. It's probably a better idea to do something like this:

```
while (cin >> toRead && allIsGoodFor(toRead)) {
    do something with toRead;
}
```

Comment: Downvoter: Is my logic incorrect here? Is there something I can do to improve this answer?

Comment: This simply is not how you write input loops.

Comment: I like this ans (so I gave +1), but please clean `some condition isn't true about toRead` up.

Comment: Perhaps `std::getline(tokenizer, line, ' ')` might be better.

Comment: Whenever you perform input, you _must_ test the result of the input operation.

Comment: @Charles Is there any reason to use `getline` here rather than the stream extraction operator?

Comment: @templatetypedef eh, not really

Comment: I was refering to `getline(std::cin, line);` and `cin >> toRead;`

Comment: @NeilButterworth Oh wow, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It's giving error :-
 stack<string> st;
 string line;
 getline(cin,line);
 istringstream tokenizer(line);//Error - no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ and ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’)
 for(string str;line>>str)
        {
            cin>>str;
            st.push(str); 
        }

Comment: @NiteshSingh I had a typo in the original code. Can you use the updated version?

Answer (score -2):

Try doing

```
stack<string> st;
string str;
while(str!="\n")
{
cin>>str;
if(str == "\n")
{
break;
}
st.push(str);
}
```

And see if that works.
And if not, then try

```
while ((str = cin.get()) != '\n')
```

instead of

```
while(str!="\n")
```

Comment: I don't think this will work correctly - `cin` skips over whitespace and therefore you'll never read a newline.